# Find nearest neighbour points in 2D Array

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a 2D array with various entries at different positions. However some positions have same value (say 5). I need to find the nearest block with value 5 from any other positioned element.!

Image is in this link :)
[This is the image to understand the problem better](http://corpopolis.com/images/pixels.png)

In this pic above. We can use the concept of Digital Image Processing to find the m-distance between each blocks. But if the problem space is too big ( suppose an array of 100X100 or 200X200) then the solution in this way will be time taking.

In way to solution I found out these links.
[Wikipedia Link for Nearest Neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search)

Apart from this how to map this whole thing in programming...?

Comment: Have a `2d` array where?

Comment: Will you query this nearest search only once or multiple times for different positions?

Comment: You'd need a 2D KD-tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdtree

Answer (score 1):

You can try any PL/SQL code for this, then you can get the nearest point from there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (maybe not most efficient) way is if you use the Wikipedia method #1 which is as follows:

Loop though all the coordinate pairs, finding the distance between them. Formula: sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)

Keep track of which pair are closest to the point you are testing, and the closest distance.

After each calculation, test if the distance is shorter; if so, then overwrite the distance and closest-pair variables.

I can expand this if you like.

Comment: Scott, if you go for this.. it is fine for few points.. but if you are dealing with 10thousands points at the same time, this wont be a very good approach.. I am planning this for a map based arena, where I have 10405 points stored in a database.